# Apollo Client - reading from cache

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

React + Apollo client app. I'm trying to read from my cache using `readQuery` but can't read the cached fields.

Here's a rundown:

Component `SinglePost` invokes `useQuery` which executes my `GET_POST` query and caches the result. `GET_POST` query returns type `Post!`. All is fine, dev tools show that `ROOT_QUERY` contains a field called **getPost** with that post.

```
const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_POST, {
    variables: {
      postID,
    }
});
```

`SinglePost` has a child component `DeleteButton` that deletes a comment on click. It invokes `useMutation` and deletes a comment. `DELETE_COMMENT` query returns type `Comment!`.

```
const [deleteComment] = useMutation(DELETE_COMMENT, {
    variables: {
      postID,
      commentID,
    },
});
```

Post has an array of comments, and now I need to update its array in the cache and remove the deleted comment. I use `update` function within the `deleteComment` mutation to get the cache object and use `readQuery` to get the **getPost** field from it, but it returns **null**, even though it's there in the dev tools.

```
update(cache, result) {
  const cacheData = cache.readQuery({
    query: GET_POST,
  });
  // code that doesn't run because cacheData is null
}
```

I suspect when mutating posts via mutations that return a `Post` type it successfully reads the **getPost** field, but when mutation queries return a `Comment` type it can't read **getPost** in its mutation hook... because there's no reference to a `Post` type?

For now I'm using `refetchQueries` as a workaround. I don't like making extra calls to the server, but my smooth brain just can't figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you must pass the same variable (`postID`)

Comment: You're right!!! I forgot the variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, no variables were ever passed to the query.

```
update(cache, result) {
  const cacheData = cache.readQuery({
    query: GET_POST,
    variables: {
      postID
    }
  });
}
```